# Why is it crucial that $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal in the definition of $\kappa$-accessible categories?

Tags: category-theory, cardinals, locally-presentable-categories, accessible-categories

In the definition of a $\kappa$-accessible (or presentable) category, the cardinal $\kappa$ is always supposed to be regular.

What happens in the irregular case?

Comment: (*singular*, rather than irregular.)

Comment: Don't you automatically get $\kappa^+$-accessibility from $\kappa$-accessibility if $\kappa$ is singular? If you have a $\kappa$-directed set with $\kappa$ singular, it is automatically $\kappa^+$-directed.

Comment: I think the answer to your first question is "no". For $\kappa < \lambda$ both regular, $\kappa$-accessibility doesn't necessarily imply $\lambda$-accessibility.
I agree that in practice it is super easy to change $\kappa$ and use $\kappa^+$. So the question is philosophical. Where do we use this assumption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following exercise is found in [Adámek and Rosický, *Locally presentable and accessible categories*]:

> **1.b Non-regular cardinals**
>
> [...]
>
> (2) Prove that if the concept of a $\lambda$-directed colimit is extended from regular cardinals to all infinite cardinals $\lambda$, then the following holds: if $\lambda_0$ is the cofinality of $\lambda$, then $\lambda$-directed colimits can always be reduced to $\lambda_0$-directed ones. In contrast, if $\lambda_0 < \lambda$ are two regular cardinals, verify that $\lambda$-directed colimits cannot be reduced to $\lambda_0$-directed ones: find a category with $\lambda_0$-directed colimits which fails to have $\lambda$-directed colimits.
>
> (3) Suppose we delete the requirement that $\lambda$ be regular from the definition of a locally $\lambda$-presentable category. Prove that then a category is locally $\lambda$-presentable if it is locally $\lambda_0$-presentable, where $\lambda_0$ is the cofinality of $\lambda$.

Comment: Ok, so the conclusion is that all the definitions work fine with singular cardinals.